# c# Intersection and Union not working correctly

Tags: c#, linq, search, intersection

I am using C# 4.0 in VS 2010 and trying to produce either an intersection or a union of n sets of objects.

The following works correctly:

```
IEnumerable<String> t1 = new List<string>() { "one", "two", "three" };
IEnumerable<String> t2 = new List<string>() { "three", "four", "five" };

List<String> tInt = t1.Intersect(t2).ToList<String>();
List<String> tUnion = t1.Union(t2).ToList<String>();
//  this also works
t1 = t1.Union(t2);
//  as does this (but not at the same time!)
t1 = t1.Intersect(t2);
```

However, the following doesn't. These are code snippets.

My class is:

```
 public class ICD10
{
    public string ICD10Code { get; set; }
    public string ICD10CodeSearchTitle { get; set; }
}
```

In the following:

```
IEnumerable<ICD10Codes> codes = Enumerable.Empty<ICD10Codes>();
IEnumerable<ICD10Codes> codesTemp;
List<List<String>> terms;
//  I create terms here ----
// and then ...
foreach (List<string> item in terms)
{
    //  the following line produces the correct results
    codesTemp = dataContextCommonCodes.ICD10Codes.Where(e => item.Any(k => e.ICD10CodeSearchTitle.Contains(k)));

    if (codes.Count() == 0)
    {
        codes = codesTemp;
    }
    else if (intersectionRequired)
    {
        codes = codes.Intersect(codesTemp, new ICD10Comparer());
    }
    else
    {
        codes = codes.Union(codesTemp, new ICD10Comparer());
    }                
}
return codes;
```

The above only ever returns the results of the last item searched.

I also added my own comparer just in case, but this made no difference:

```
public class ICD10Comparer : IEqualityComparer<ICD10Codes>
{
    public bool Equals(ICD10Codes Code1, ICD10Codes Code2)
    {
        if (Code1.ICD10Code == Code2.ICD10Code) { return true; }
        return false;
    }
    public int GetHashCode(ICD10Codes Code1)
    {
        return Code1.ICD10Code.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

I am certain I am overlooking something obvious - I just cannot see what it is!

Comment: Try moving the declaration of `codesTemp` inside the loop, ie `IEnumerable<ICD10Codes> codesTemp = dataContextCommonCodes.ICD1...`.

Comment: Thanks Joachim, nice thought. Sadly, it makes no difference.

Comment: Missed one thing, you'll want to also do `List<string> tmpItem = item;` and use `tmpItem` instead of `item` in the `dataContextCommonCodes` Linq expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code:  `return codes;`  returns a deferred enumerable.  None of the queries have been executed to fill the set.  Some queries get executed each time through the loop to make a Count though.

This deferred execution is a problem because of the closure issue... at the return, `item` is bound to the last loop execution.

Resolve this by forcing the queries to execute in each loop execution:

```
if (codes.Count() == 0)
{
    codes = codesTemp.ToList();
}
else if (intersectionRequired)
{
    codes = codes.Intersect(codesTemp, new ICD10Comparer()).ToList();
}
else
{
    codes = codes.Union(codesTemp, new ICD10Comparer()).ToList();
}
```

Comment: +1 Yep, this is the explanation, an alternative is to save `item` in a temporary variable declared inside the loop so it's never updated.

Comment: +1 Many thanks David, just the job, spot on and all the other phrases leading to thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

if you are using an own comparer, you should take a look at the correct implementation of the `GetHashCode` function. the linq operators use this comparison too. you can take a look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.80).aspx

you could try changing the hash function to "return 0", to see if it is the problem. `ICD10Code.GetHashCode` will return perhaps different values if it is a class object

Answer (score 0):

Your problem definitely is not connect to `Intersect` or `Union` LINQ extension methods. I've just tested following:

```
var t1 = new List<ICD10>()
    {
        new ICD10() { ICD10Code = "123" },
        new ICD10() { ICD10Code = "234" },
        new ICD10() { ICD10Code = "345" }
    };
var t2 = new List<ICD10>()
    {
        new ICD10() { ICD10Code = "234" },
        new ICD10() { ICD10Code = "456" }
    };

// returns list with just one element - the one with ICF10Code == "234"
var results = t1.Intersect(t2, new ICD10Comparer()).ToList();

// return list with 4 elements
var results2 = t1.Union(t2, new ICD10Comparer()).ToList();
```

Using your `ICD10` and `ICD10Comparer` classes declarations. Everything works just fine! You have to search for bug in your custom code, because LINQ works just fine.

Comment: His expression using `item` doesn't work quite as well in a loop since `item` changes before the expression is evaluated.